# Best way for spring boot password encryption not using BCryptPasswordEncoder?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

How can i encrypt user login password apart from BCryptPasswordEncoder.
Suppose I'm not using this dependency.

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` is just another encoder. Spring provides implementations of many such encoders. You can use implementations of different one way hash algorithms like SHA-256, SHA-512 etc. Java provides implementations of the same in `java.security` package. Check `java.security.MessageDigest` class. 
One advantage of using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` like encoders is that you do not need to generate random password salt yourself. It takes care of it and uses random salt implicitly and that's why generates different encoded string every time for the same Plain text.

Answer (score 0):

After searching I figured out that best practice is to use encoder as Chetan Ahirrao
said.
the solution i found is to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and use BCryptPasswordEncoder

```
 @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
```